# Diff Eq. : Find an explicit solution of $y^2 - 1 = y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y' = y^2 - 1$$

I think this cannot be solved using the integration factor method because of the square power of the y.

Attempted: 
$$ \frac{y'}{y^2} = -1 $$
$$ y^{-1} = t + C $$
$$ \frac{1}{y} =  t + C$$

It's not the right answer.

How do I go about solving this?
Thanks.

Comment: The first step is wrong. It should be $\frac{y'}{y^2-1}=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an algebra error at the beginning. From $y'=y^2-1$ it is not correct to conclude that $\frac{y'}{y^2}=-1$. We *could* conclude that $\frac{y'}{y^2}=-\frac{1}{y^2}$, but that is not helpful.  Our DE is *separable*, and there is a standard method for dealing with separable equations.

**If** $y^2\ne 1$, we can divide by $y^2-1$, and obtain
$$\frac{y'}{y^2-1}=1.$$
The following notation is more common in beginning DE courses:
$$\frac{dy}{y^2-1}=dt.$$
Integrate on both sides. On the left, use the partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{1}{y^2-1}=\left(\frac{1}{y-1}-\frac{1}{y+1}\right).$$
when we integrate, we get
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln(|y-1|)-\ln(|y+1|)\right)=t+C.$$
Multiply through by $2$, and take the exponential of both sides. After a while you should be able to find an explicit expression for $y$.  Don't forget the two special solutions $y\equiv 1$ and $y\equiv -1$. (You may have an initial condition that lets you not bother with them.)

Comment: put in absolute values in the logarithms and you have it for all three regions.

Comment: @Will Jagy: Thanks, it is better that way, in the absence of an initial condition.

Answer (score 2):

$$ y = 1$$
$$ y = -1$$
There are also non-constant  solutions, for which
$$  \frac{y'}{y^2 - 1} = 1.  $$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{y^\prime}{y^2-1} = 1$$

Then you integrate. This is a Ricatti equation.

The integration will involve argth.

Comment: or partial fractions, probably more familiar

Comment: indeed, this is much better in this case :)

Comment: I put in a CW post with how it works out using tanh and coth, although not how to get there with the inverse functions. CW means, should it get any votes, it will not affect my collected points ("reputation"). It also means that many, many people should be allowed to edit it. Give that a try if you think of something more suitable there than in your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I quite like @GHL's idea of going straight to the hyperbolic trigonometric functions. 
I cannot say I ever really used those in a beginning ODE course, but it is a good idea.
So I thought of putting that information here as community wiki.

We have $$ \frac{d}{dx} \cosh x = \sinh x,$$
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \sinh x = \cosh x,$$ and
$$  \cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1.  $$

They do have Latex for the hyperbolic tangent and cotangent, but not secant and cosecant, ALRIGHT I'M USING OPERATORNAME.
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \tanh x =  \operatorname{sech}^2  x,$$
$$ \frac{d}{dx}  \operatorname{sech}  x = -  \operatorname{sech}  x \; \tanh x,$$
$$  \tanh^2  x +   \operatorname{sech}^2  x = 1.   $$ 
Next
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \coth x = -  \operatorname{csch}^2  x,$$
$$ \frac{d}{dx}  \operatorname{csch}  x = -  \operatorname{csch}  x \; \coth x,$$
$$  \coth^2  x -  \, \operatorname{csch}^2 \, x = 1.   $$

For the problem at hand, $y' = y^2 - 1,$ for $|y| < 1$ we use
$$  \tanh^2  x - 1 = -   \operatorname{sech}^2  x  $$
and
$$ \frac{d}{dx} (- \tanh x) = -  \operatorname{sech}^2  x,$$
where we may also shift $x$ to any $x - C,$ and $y = - \tanh(x-C).$

For $y > 1,$
we use
$$  \coth^2  x - 1 =  \operatorname{csch}^2  x ,   $$
and
$$ \frac{d}{dx} ( - \coth x) =   \operatorname{csch}^2  x.$$
We may also shift $x$ to any $x - C,$ and $y = - \coth(x-C),$ but only for $x < C$ which is where the particular solution goes to infinity.

For $y < -1,$
we use
$$  \coth^2  x - 1 =  \operatorname{csch}^2  x ,   $$
and
$$ \frac{d}{dx} ( - \coth x) =   \operatorname{csch}^2  x.$$
We may also shift $x$ to any $x - C,$ and $y = - \coth(x-C),$ but only for $x > C.$ In this case the curve begins with $y$ at negative infinity and eventually it gets close to the $y = -1$ constant solution in forward time.

Comment: Boo to mbox. `\operatorname{sech}x` all the way, for consistent spacing with other operators. $\operatorname{sech}x$